# "Both stand valid" or "Both stands valid"

Tags: word-usage, phrases, verb-forms, singular-vs-plural, confusable

I was answering a question in ELL and I got stuck between the usage of  *'stand'* and *'stands'* in the phrase *'both stand/stands valid'*. Which one is the correct version?

Context:

> (Question) Which is correct ? "I was alone since last month" or "I had been alone since last month" ?
>   (Answer) "Both stands valid as neither of them are incorrect"

Comment: What are 'both'? More than one? Then a plural verb. Also, alternative way to tell that is - *"...both **are** valid"*.

Comment: I know 'are' can be used. But that's not my question. "Both" refers to "two among two", yes, a plural verb. Do you want me to elaborate on the context to give you a little more information ?

Comment: I believe it is "stands", the "plural verb" helped me...Thanks.

Comment: (Question) _Which is correct ? "I was alone since last month"_  or _"I had been alone since last month" ?_  (Answer) _"Both stands valid as neither of them are incorrect"_

Comment: @VarunKN - I think you have misunderstood.  The plural form is **stand**, not *stands*.  I *stand*, you *stand*, it *stands*, but **they stand**.  Since there are two things, **they stand** and **both stand**.

Comment: @VarunKN I think stangdon understand your confusion right. I was a bit surprised since I wouldn't expect someone who has a good command of English like you would have a problem with *Both is/are*, but it could happen, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

> Which is correct? Option A **OR** Option B?

If that's the case, there are two options and if you want to include them or call them as 'both', they are plural.

So,

> Both **are** correct 
>  Both **are** valid 
>  Both **stand** valid

**BUT**

You are using 'neither' which takes a **singular** verb.

> *"....as neither of them **is** incorrect"*

Comment: A note on *neither*: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are.